# Bash - Is it a good idea to make all variables local?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a compiler that compiles into bash. It seems like a pain to declare some variables as local and some as global - I can declare variables as local even when I'm not inside a function. Is it a good idea to make all variables local in bash?

Comment: No, you cannot declare variables local outside of a function. `bash` is no different from other languages in the sense that local variables allow your function to be used without worrying about changes they may make to the global state. You just need to be aware that `bash` uses *dynamic* scoping, not static/lexical scoping, and understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Please clarify what "*compiles into `bash`*" means.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `global` variables only when needed because it makes it harder to debug; the bash official docs say this regarding `local` variables:

> local [option] [name[=value] ...] .
>
> For each argument, a local variable
>   named name is created, and assigned value. The option can be any of
>   the options accepted by declare. When local is used within a function,
>   it causes the variable name to have a visible scope restricted to that
>   function and its children. With no operands, local writes a list of
>   local variables to the standard output. It is an error to use local
>   when not within a function. The return status is 0 unless local is
>   used outside a function, an invalid name is supplied, or name is a
>   read‐ only variable.

You should `local` variables only when you're in a function otherwise it will error.

You should also take a look at what [variable scope means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). If you make all variables global scope, then its going to be painful to debug. If you make `var a` global scope, and then *[shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)* it (accidentally maybe) within a function as `var a`, creating a local scope, you'll make it even harder to debug.